# How do I call a string method twice in Java without repeating the whole method?

Tags: java, function, methods

What I am trying to do is prompt a user to enter their first and last name by calling a function twice. First call would be for the first name and the second call would be for the last name. The program would then concatenate and display "Hello, firstname lastname!" I feel like I am very close to the correct outcome but I am obviously missing something. New guy here. Thank you for any and all responses.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class firstLastName2 {
  static String F_NAME;
  static String L_NAME;
  static String name;
  static void firstName(String name) {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter your first name.");
    F_NAME = keyboard.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Please enter your last name.");
    L_NAME = keyboard.nextLine();
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    firstName(name);
    System.out.println("Hello, " + F_NAME + " " + L_NAME + "!");
  }
}
```

Comment: What problem you are facing now? Your current code doesn't show any effort about what you are trying to do.

Comment: It is not clear what you want. Your code has the correct output for me.

Comment: I am trying to call the function twice, first passing a prompt string for the 
user's first name, followed by a second call which passes a prompt string for the user's last name.

Comment: Why do you need to call a function twice? The method firstName (which is badly named - should be called e.g. getNames) does what you need.

Comment: I changed it to getNames. Thank you for that feedback. I realize that it does what I need but the course I am taking asks for this in the problem statement. I have tried different ways to call twice without repeating the entire function with no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to call a function twice, then i suggest that the function return the user input and receive the question text. Your code seem to be right.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class firstLastName2 {
  static Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

  static String getUserInput(String question) {
    System.out.println(question);
    return keyboard.nextLine();
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String name = getUserInput("Please enter your first name.");
    String sunrName = getUserInput("Please enter your last name.");
    System.out.println(String.format("Hello, %s %s!", name , surName));
  }
}
```

Comment: It seems overkilling to write a method for this purpose I think. And remove property from class also a bad idea when OP design that way.

Comment: I know, but i was only trying to answer the question with minimun modifications to original code. As you say is not a good idea to make a blocking calll inside a class method. I disagree with what you say about removing class methods, as it can be a good idea in a concurrency scenario, as if you have the chance of having a call from the same VM from different threads at the same time, access to static class members may be syncrhonized to avoid unexpected behaviours in run time

Comment: _remove property from class_ Actually I am saying about not static field, create an instance of class and do what you want to do.